# How can I get data out of NSURLRequest config object

Tags: ios, angularjs, json, nsurlrequest

I have an Angular web build inside an iOS app and want to `POST` requests up to the native layer with some `JSON` that I can use to build some native functionality. I am using the old `UIWebView` (because Angular) so am using an `NSURLProtocol` to intercept the request. This works and I can break at the point that the request comes in. The problem is that I can not see the `JSON` in the data property at this point because it is not the response. The request is still in the config object but I have no idea how to grab this.

My angular code for creating the post is currently like this:

```
var newdata = $.param({
            json: JSON.stringify({
                name: "Lee"
            })
        });

        $http.post(url, newdata)
```

and in my `NSURLProtocol` class I am successfully intercepting this POST in this method but the HTTPBody property is nil:

```
override class func canInitWithRequest(request:NSURLRequest) -> Bool {

        if (request.URL!.absoluteString as NSString).containsString("request_media_gallery") {

            if(request.HTTPBody != nil){

                let data:NSData = request.HTTPBody!
                print(data)
            }
            return true
        }
        return request.URL?.host == "file"
    }
```

If I debug this in chrome I get a 405 because of CORS but I can see that my request object does not have any data but does have a config object. Here's the console log from Chrome:

[image: console log]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the time a URL request gets down to the protocol layer, IIRC, the URL Loading System sanitizes it in a lot of ways.  In particular, if a request has an `HTTPBody` object associated with it, it basically does this:

```
req.HTTPBodyStream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithData:req.HTTPBody];
req.HTTPBody = nil;
```

As a result, to get the data, you need to read from the `HTTPBodyStream`, regardless of whether the request was originally created with an `NSData` object or a body stream.

Comment: So how do we read from this NSInputStream? Mine seems to say "no bytes available"

Comment: Annoyingly, the bytes don't actually become available until a later cycle of the run loop.  To handle reading: 1.  Set yourself as the stream's delegate.  2.  Schedule it in a run loop.  3.  Open the stream.  4.  Implement the bytes available delegate methods.  5.  Do your work after it says there are bytes available.